# html file_get_contents() encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, file-get-contents, mb-convert-encoding

I try to display html content file into php.

```
$file_to_load = "index.html";    
$html_page = file_get_contents($file_to_load);
```

But it's output :

```
�<�!�D�O�C�T�Y�P�E� �h�t�m�l�>���<�h�t�m�l�>��
```

And

```
mb_convert_encoding($html_page , 'UTF-8' , 'UTF-8');
=> "??<�!DOCTYPE html> <�html> <�head> <�title>"
```

I can't be rid of the "�" ! I tri different encoding like : "UTF-16 LE" (atom auto detect that on the html file), "ASCII" ...

What I'm doing wrong ? Someone have the same issue and find a solution ?

Comment: That looks more like real unicode encoding.

Comment: have you tried changing the encoding of `index.html` to `utf-8` in your text editor ?